# Most energy-efficient authentication protocol?

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman, authentication, key-exchange, lightweight

I am looking for a cryptographic protocol that is as energy-efficient as possible. I am talking about battery drain. Alice wants to do a mutual authentication with Bob. Maybe symmetric is good, maybe asymmetric with PFS is better. I am interested in knowing the best state-of-the-art, non-patented solutions for this issue.

It would also be nice to know which primitives for hashes, ciphers, groups etc. tend to be most efficent. The context is for IoT devices.

Thank you!

Comment: You may have a look at arduino crypto project - https://rweather.github.io/arduinolibs/crypto.html, where processing times could give you at least baseline performance comparison.

Comment: You need to specify what hardware you are using, otherwise there's no way to answer.